# How I can send post Request Angular 5?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have next function for send request

```
addSite(address, username, password, device_token, os_type){
    this.headers = (new HttpHeaders())
      .set('Content-type', 'application/json')
      .set('Access-Control-Allow-Method', 'POST');

    let params = new HttpParams();
    params.set('username', username)
          .set('password', password)
          .set('device_token', device_token)
          .set('os_type', os_type);
    return this.http.post(`${address + Config.API_URL}, params,
      {headers: this.headers} )
  }
}
```

I always Get error http://joxi.net/52aXvbVtGpReqm , it's happened when I doing request without params. But I have params, Please help me to find mistake.

Comment: Compare your handling of `HttpParams` and `HttpHeaders` - why are they different? Both are immutable, both of their `set` methods return a new object.

Comment: Looks like you are sending params where you should be sending the post body. [HttpClient Guide](https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-post-request).

Comment: Excuse me, I'm new, can you make an example for me? I think that the parameters should be separate from Header, is not?

Comment: @R.Richards Why ? I send url=${address + Config.API_URL}, params, and headers. so much as in the example

Comment: about the immutability: https://medium.com/spektrakel-blog/angular-httpclient-enforces-immutability-dad161d8714b and make sure that you actually are supposed to send as params, seems a bit weird to me, usually we don't expose credentials like that...

Comment: You should create FormData() object and set the values and send it as post body

Comment: Never send passwords in clear text. Not ever.

Comment: The second argument of http.post must be the body of your post.

Comment: @DDDSoft I try next Request but still have error 
      return this.http.post(address + Config.API_URL, {
        username: username,
        password: password,
        device_token: device_token,
        os_type: os_type
      }, httpOptions )
  }

Comment: Does you get the error back from the server or is it ionic who is throwing it?

Comment: @DDDSoft I get error from server but when I use Postman I Get correct answer. I think erorr in my code

Comment: What must your post-action exactly do? What is the purpose of username, password, device_token, os_type?

Comment: I need get token. os_type and devise_token are optional.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

send the param as form data like this

```
addSite(address, username, password, device_token, os_type){
    this.headers = (new HttpHeaders())
      .set('Content-type', 'application/json')
      .set('Access-Control-Allow-Method', 'POST');

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('username', username);
    formData.append('password', password);
    formData.append('device_token', device_token);
    formData.append('os_type', os_type);
    return this.http.post(`${address + Config.API_URL}, formData,
      {headers: this.headers} )
  }
}
```

Comment: I try, my formData is empty when I send request.

Comment: are you sure your data values are not empty ?

Comment: You was right, I only changed header to the
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
and it works.

Comment: I am glad that i could help. but its sad someone gave downvote for my answer when it actually helped the question.